# Could you please provide me with comments on a Java game of mine?

Tags: java, user-feedback, pulpcore

I have marked this question as community wiki, so no rep points are thrown around.

I made this game, [Forest Defender](http://www.perhac.com/shared/forest-defender/index.html), a proof-of-feasibility little project, which I would like to share with you and collect your constructive comments, first impressions, etc. 
It is a the first playable (and enjoyable) game I have released to the public, so I am, naturally, very eager to get some recognition by you, as my peers. I read in a StackOverflow blog, that

> One of the major reasons we created Stack Overflow to give every programmer a chance to be recognized by their peers. Recognized for their knowledge, their passion, [...]

It comes in the form of a Java applet, I used an animation framework called PulpCore and I must say that it's been extremely enjoyable to work with it. I do recommend to people interested in Java game development.

Since the product is free, fun, entirely commercial-free and I am willing to share the code to it (on request), I thought it would be OK to post this as a topic here. Moderators, please feel free to move this to another place if you deem the other place more appropriate.

http://www.perhac.com/shared/forest-defender/index.html

**EDIT**

Did anyone else encounter a blue screen? Any errors or problems? If so, which OS and Java version were you using?

**EDIT2**

As many suggested some areas of the game are not very readable, I spent some time with photoshop to work on a better readable and cleaner design. The instructions section is now easier to read, the in-game information panel's background was replaced, and, huh, the credits screen is clearer :-)  I also wanted users to provide their name or alias, so that later a high-score table could be shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Strengths:

1. The game appears reliable and stable. No crashes after a half hour of gameplay.
2. Music is pretty good for an indy game. Most independent developers either skip music and sound all together, or use some freebie sample they found that drives me crazy by being boring, repetitive, or just downright painful to listen to.

### Opportunities:

1. You lose points for an unoriginal idea. You've basically created a [Desktop Tower Defense](http://www.handdrawngames.com/DesktopTD/Game.asp) clone. Don't get me wrong, you're in good company. It's a compelling form of gameplay, and you're hardly the first to copy it. If you're doing this as a way to learn a new language, or experiment with tools, then more power to you, but linking to the original creator wouldn't hurt. It doesn't make your game less interesting if you give credit where it's due.
2. On the welcome menu, the foreground and background colours of the text are too similar. This makes the text difficult to read. Consider using a higher contrast pair of colours.
3. The tool tips in the Play screen can be cut off if your mouse cursor is too far to the left or right. They're similarly difficult to read to due to the low contrast between the foreground and background. Consider altering the background layer to be less transparent.
4. During gameplay the statistics and info panel on the right side of the screen is unclear. Consider breaking it into sections:

   - This wave
   - Next wave
   - Money & lives
5. Money & lives are more important, so put them at the top. Money is also linked to purchasing, so having it nearer the tower purchase buttons would make sense.
6. I'm not really clear on what the "R" and "W" indicators with the coloured blobs are trying to show me.
7. I generally want to place several towers at the same time, especially at the start of the game. Allow me to place another tower immediately after placing the first, don't make me go back to the right-hand panel and select which tower I want a second time.
8. You say "I am willing to share the code to it (on request)". I think keeping the code to yourself is a bad idea. Just throw the code up on Github and release it under an open source license. You stand to gain nothing by keeping it hidden.

Comment: There can never be too many Tower Defense clones :)

Comment: wow, thank you. I am aware of some of the game's weaknesses you mentioned. These will be definitely fixed in the second version. (bad choice of colors, unclear info panel, the money and lives info in particular). However, I find that you have not spent 30 seconds clicking through the game instructions. The game does allow you to build multiple units, if you hold Shift. There is a short and straightforward strategy guide you could visit (there's a link in the Info screen and in the in-game menu). The game is not supposed to be simple, so I can't avoid making people read instructions...

Comment: @fish, precisely. I didn't ever cross my mind to give credit to any of the other tower defence games creators. There are some original ideas in this variation :-)

Comment: "I find that you have not spent 30 seconds clicking through the game instructions." This is very typical of end users. Hardly anyone reads instructions. If I were you, I'd scrap the instructions and implement a short tutorial, if possible; that seems to be the common thing to do nowadays. The tooltips were a great way for you to avoid instructions as well; you could've buried those explanations in the instructions but instead you put them in the user's face, when the user needed to know them. Do the same thing with everything else.

Comment: @Ricket, I added a tutorial level as you suggested. I wanted to avoid all intricacies of programming a tutorial, but I managed to find a compromise in the end :-)

Comment: Oh, wow. Somehow the first time I played it, I only noticed the traps, not the tower buttons. I was placing traps everywhere and wondering why only some of them affected the creeps! This tutorial really sorts things out. The overall feel of the game is still just not quite as polished as other games I've played though, but I can't put my finger on it... :-\

Answer (score 5):

I like it - nice little game

A few suggestions (purely in the spirit of improving it!):

1. When placing towers for the first time it's a bit hard to see where you can / cannot place them. Maybe show a ghost version of the tower when you are hovering over a spot?
2. Suggestion to make it really pretty - why not put a momentum / drag factor in the creeps speed? This would make it look even more fluid and dynamic, and you could create lots more interesting tower dynamics (e.g. some creeps would take a lot of time to get up to speed if you stopped them dead)
3. Suggest restructuring the user interface panel - in particular I found it a little unintuitive to have the sub-panel for the tower appear where you have to press "X" to escape back to see your money and lives etc.

Comment: I very much like your comments. Thank you, some very neat ideas. A tip for you: keyboard shortcuts. right hand on the mouse, left on the Q,W,S,F,1,2,3,4,5 Keys. (close the tower/trap/monster info panel by pressing W, which will then show you the level info) I was running out of space, next release will be 800x600, only to give me more space for the side panel. I really need to make it more clear. Thanks for all the other suggestions!

Comment: No worries - glad to be helpful. By the way - another tip from years of experience is that people never read the manual :-)

Comment: the third bullet point is now number one on my list :-) re-visit in a few days' time to see if it's to your taste :-)

Answer (score 4):

A nice little game, and well executed.  Small disclaimer: I'm not a huge fan of the tower defense clones personally.  I played the original a lot, then the ants version, and then my attention turned to other games.  So please don't read too much into my small enthusiasm.

Clear strengths: as others have said, the graphics are crisp, action is swift, reasonable selection of enemies and defenses, decent music.

Minor weaknesses: In addition to what Brian and Mikera have said, my only real (small) issue with the game was being able to see how much money I had left to spend.  I found it by running out.  Nice effect, incidentally, having the amount get larger when I run out, in case I hadn't noticed (I hadn't).

Also, a tooltip over the Resistant/Weak section would answer questions like Brian's above.  I already knew, because I'd read the help and strategy, but lots of people will just jump into the game.

Well done.  If this is your first attempt, I expect great things.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. To be honest, I find it also quite annoying that the amount of funds available is not visible at all times (lack of space) :-), that's number one on my list of changes to be made for the second version. I especially like your suggestion to show a tooltip for the R/W indicators. why didn't I think of that? Thank you, again. And, yes, it was my first attempt with pulpCore and Java game development.

Answer (score 3):

Peter, it's a fun game. Thanks. :) I'm not sure it'll displace my Angry Birds addiction, but playing through the tutorial was definitely fun.

I'm very glad I read about the "shift" speedup here, before playing, though. By the time it was mentioned in the tutorial, I would have been very tired of repeated clicking without it.

In fact, I'd suggest removing the 'shift' aspect, and make 'place the selected item again' the default behaviour, without modifiers.

Bouncing the money when it reached 0 was a *giant* help. Good idea there.

Thanks, and have fun. :)

Answer (score 3):

Please give the players the option to lower and / or mute the sound!

Comment: you can lower or mute the music, in the in-game menu. But it's not a bad idea to provide a kill-all-sounds-button :-) I think I could add that one. I just thought the user interface is already very crowded. Am running out of space.

Comment: +1 for a mute button... I specifically found myself looking for one (I hard already started playing the game and wanted to mute it so I could continue listening to the music I was already listening to)

Answer (score 3):

Kudos on a game that runs quickly and smoothly!

1. Entrance/Exit on the maps is not always obvious. Perhaps simple arrows pointing in/out of the game play area would work.
2. Not obvious that you have to click during the tutorial tooltips.
3. Tooltip text over towers, traps, etc might look nicer if all of the stats were justified

   ```
   Fast Tower

     Cost: XXX
   Damage: XXX
    Speed: XXX
    Range: XXX
   ```
4. Reiterate the need to money/lives more obvious. Perhaps a persistent display that doesn't change regardless of tower placement vs. tower upgrade mode.

Comment: you know, it can't believe it never occurred to me to include the arrows for the creeps' direction of travel. I probably will, now that I think about it :-) thanks for your other comments too.

Comment: +1 for arrows on entrance/exit and for a "[click to continue]" message on the bottom of the click-through instructions

Comment: I will add more `click to continue` messages throughout the game.

Comment: added arrows in every  level to indicate which way the creeps are gonna go. Also added a click to dismiss message in the tutorial screens. Thanks for feedback